# Add OLE Object into Word table with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex, ole

I am trying to insert ActiveX Control labels into a table's cell in Word with a VBA script. I know how to insert text into a table with VBA, but can't figure out how to insert the label. The script below would add text to a Table 1, Cell 1,1.

```
 ThisDocument.Tables(1).cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "hello"
```

I found a few scripts for inserting ActiveX controls, but I am getting stuck at how to place it in the table cell (links to script instructions at bottom). Here is my best guess, but it is not working.

```
 ThisDocument.Tables(1).cell(1, 1).InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.Label.1"
```

The error I am getting highlights 'InlineShapes' and reads:

> Compile Error: Method or data member not found

[InlineShapes.AddOLEControl method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addolecontrol)

[AddOLEControl Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171533(v%3Doffice.11))

Comment: Have you tried `ThisDocument.Tables(1).cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ...`?

Comment: That is correct- I missed the 'range' piece.  ThisDocument.Tables(3).cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.Label.1"

Comment: Cool. So... does it work or not? (I'm not familiar with Word's object model at all)

Comment: Yes it does work, thank you!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon & Jessica: unless you really know you want to use `ThisDocument` to identify a file, do ***not use*** it. It refers specifically to the file containing the macro code. Usually, one uses `ActiveDocument` (or better, a `Document` object referring to a specific document).